# GDB error while debugging in CLion

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, mingw, clion

I have this code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

const int N = 100;
int ar[N][N];

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

I set breakpoint and start debugger and when i'm trying to watch content of whole array gdb throws exception:

```
../../../../src/gdb-7.11.1/gdb/gdbtypes.c:4575: internal-error: copy_type: Assertion `TYPE_OBJFILE_OWNED (type)' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
```

But debugger works with this code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

const int N = 100;
long long int ar[N][100];

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

In first case I can watch value of single element of array.
MinGW-w64 5.0 
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.11.1

Comment: this is working good for me 
(gdb) p ar
$1 = {{0 <repeats 100 times>} <repeats 100 times>}
(gdb) n
0x000000000040078d in __libc_csu_init ()

Comment: Probably this bug: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20630.

Comment: It works from console but CLion says Collecting data.. then gdb exits with code 3.